# Saving spectrogram figures in a loop for wav files

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, spectrogram

I'm attempting to generate spectrograms so that I could compare them to word samples later for a very basic speech recognition project. This is being done in a loop. The code is as follows:

```
folder = '<<my directory path>>';
files = dir(fullfile(folder,'*.wav'));
for k = 1:length(files)
    baseFileName = files(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    [word, fs] = wavread(fullFileName);
    sound(word, fs);
    figure('visible','off');
    %%fig = figure, specgram(fullFileName, 512, fs);
    %%saveas(fig, baseFileName.fig);
end
```

My issue is in the last two lines. I want to save the spectrogram figure as a .fig file (unless you guys have a better suggestion for comparison purposes later on) and name it the same as baseFileName. I've been googling for a while now but the formatting is confusing and there isn't much about spectrogram being saved as figures.

I would prefer it if all the figures didn't pop up in the loop but I can deal.

EDIT: perhaps it will be better to store this as a matfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
for k=1:length(files)
   h=figure
   spectrogram();
   Figname = strcat(baseFileName,'.fig');
   saveas(h,Figname); 
end
```

For the figures with the format other than .fig, another method:

```
fh=figure
for k=1:length(files)
   figure(fh); 
   spectrogram();
   frm = getframe(fh);
   Figname = strcat(baseFileName,'.jpg');
   imwrite(frm.cdata, Figname);
end
```

Unfortunately it will cause error 'Unable to determine the file format from the filename' when trying to save a .fig file with this method.

Comment: I need it to save as the baseFileName.fig. It's iterating through a list of wav files with different names (e.g. dog, cat, etc), which gets temporarily stored in baseFileName for loop purposes. Also, I still need the specgram to come out the same way as when I do specgream(fullFileName, 512, fs), otherwise it doesn't look right.

edit: sorry if I'm not making much sense I'm not too familiar with MATLAB and its syntax.

Comment: I get the following errors:

Error using imwrite (line 431)
Unable to determine the file format from the filename.

Error in specAllTheFiles (line 18)
    imwrite(frm.cdata, Figname);

Comment: Indeed it does. Unfortunately it named everything fileName.wav.fig... But I can fix that part. Thank you!